# Catastrophic forgetting in spacy: rehearse function

Tags: spacy

I trained a new entity with spacy starting from the German model. To avoid catastrophic forgetting I tried two approaches.

Approach 1: Pseudo-rehearsal
As suggested in the spacy documentation, I tried with a pseudo-rehearsal approach and fed the update function with training data + revision data (data containing standard entities that are recognized). It seems that, after the first update iteration the model forgets the standard entities and recognizes only the new one. Do you have any clue why this is happening?

Approach 2: Use the rehearse function
As second approach, I tried to use the rehearse function giving as rehearsal data a text with standard entities (without annotations).
The text look like this:

```
[Gertrude liebt Katze, Paolo hat gerne Katzen,  Anastasia hat gerne Nudeln]
```

When calling the rehearse function, I got the following error:

```
  File "test.py", line 226, in <module>
new_model = train_ner(nlp, TRAIN_DATA,rehearse_data, n_iter, LABEL, output_dir, model_name)
  File "test.py", line 112, in train_ner
nlp.rehearse(set(raw_batch), sgd=optimizer, losses=r_losses)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spacy/language.py", line 503, in rehearse
    proc.rehearse(docs, sgd=get_grads, losses=losses, **config.get(name, {}))
  File "pipes.pyx", line 450, in spacy.pipeline.pipes.Tagger.rehearse
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

I checked in pipes.pyx the rehearse function where the gradient is calculated as:

gradient = scores - target

Of course I cannot subtract a list from a list, but I think I do not understand correctly the form of the rehearsal data I heve to feed the function in.
I also tried to give labeled rehearsal data in the form spacy likes:

```
rehearse_data = [
("Uber blew through $1 million a week", [(0, 4, 'ORG')]),
("Android Pay expands to Canada", [(0, 11, 'PRODUCT'), (23, 30, 'GPE')]),
("Spotify steps up Asia expansion", [(0, 8, "ORG"), (17, 21, "LOC")]),
("Google Maps launches location sharing", [(0, 11, "PRODUCT")]),
("Google rebrands its business apps", [(0, 6, "ORG")]),
("look what i found on google! ", [(21, 27, "PRODUCT")])]
```

and got the following error:

```
  File "test.py", line 228, in <module>
    new_model = train_ner(nlp, TRAIN_DATA,rehearse_data, n_iter, LABEL, output_dir, model_name)
  File "test.py", line 109, in train_ner
raw_batch = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in list(next(r_batches))]
  File "test.py", line 109, in <listcomp>
raw_batch = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in list(next(r_batches))]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spacy/language.py", line 401, in make_doc
return self.tokenizer(text)
TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got tuple)
```

Here is my code:

```
def train_ner(nlp, train_data, rehearse_data, niter, label, output_dir, model_name):

    random.seed(0)

    # Add entity recognizer to model if it's not in the pipeline

    ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")
    ner.add_label(label)  # add new entity label to entity recognizer

    # Resume training: we want to train only the new entity 
    optimizer = nlp.resume_training()


    sizes = compounding(1.0, 4.0, 1.001)

    # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
    for itn in range(n_iter):
        print("NITER", itn)
        random.shuffle(train_data)
        random.shuffle(rehearse_data)
        #batches = minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=sizes)

        #batches = get_batches(TRAIN_DATA,lang)
        losses = {}
        r_losses = {}

        r_batches = minibatch(rehearse_data,size=4)

        #for batch in batches:
        for batch in minibatch(train_data, size=4):
            print("BATCH",batch)

            texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
            print("TEXTS",type(texts))

            nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=next(dropout), losses=losses) 

            raw_batch = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in list(next(r_batches))]
            print("RAW_BATCH",raw_batch)
            nlp.rehearse(set(raw_batch), sgd=optimizer, losses=r_losses)

        print("Losses", losses)
        print("R. Losses", r_losses)

    print(nlp.get_pipe('ner').model.unseen_classes)
```